# SoapUI: memory(?) usage optimizing

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have groovy script with cycle, smth like

```
blablabla

while (true)
{
     N++

{do something}

    if (reason=='stop it!') break
}
```

Steps inside are rather huge(e.g. - repeatable test cases with big data responses). 
Incrementing N/actions inside/outside seems to be correct(Script normally works for 20+ first N).

But at one "perfect" time soapUI just freezes... I do not think it because of script code, because we just repeat actions until "REASON" trigger (it works if try trigger for small N).

So, question is: what does this problem mean exactly? Have I chance to avoid that? I need repeat scrypt many times and fill report correctly...

Sincerely,
Dmitry

Comment: SoapUI is known to leak memory, a lot. From what you supplied, it is not possible to give you a definitive answer. Try restructuring your test / script into smaller blocks.

Comment: Hi SiKing. yep, I found solution in rather some way...(just push needed data to txt file, and use it.))

Comment: But commonly - I can not add nothing to the question... It exists like it exists - big responses leads to possible fails/freezes. So, YES, other solution(optimal?) is really just to divide for smaller blocks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really memory leak of SoapUI. I investigated that data with other tools.